# Buffer records in GNU awk

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, awk

I'm trying to make a script that will live watch some logs. I have a log of requests with each request formatted something like this,

```
---
id=273482
Result=Error
---
id=342345
Result=Success
---
```

And a second log where each line has the id of the request. I need to live watch the request log and cross reference it with the second log.

```
 tail -f requestLog | awk \"BEGIN { RS = \"---\" } /Error/\" | grep --line-buffered id | sed -u ...
```

I tail -f the requestLog, use awk to split records on the "---", and then grep out the id lines. Then later I pass all that to sed -u to extract the id and xargs to go grep the second log for lines that were related to the bad requests.

The problem is the results are coming out really delayed because something (I think awk) is buffering wrong. How can I make awk read the input nonstop and flush the output everytime it sees a bad record? I'm using GNU awk by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU awk has a `fflush()` you can use to flush buffers:

```
.. | awk 'BEGIN { RS = "---" } /Error/ { print; fflush(); }' | ..
```

With this you've line buffered all the stages in the pipeline.

If you in the future have any other programs in the pipeline that don't support something like awk `fflush`, `grep --line-buffered` or `sed -u`, GNU coreutils has a more general `stdbuf` you can use with any program:

```
.. | stdbuf -o 0 any_other_command | ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix

```
tail -f requestLog|awk 'BEGIN{RS="--*"}/Error/{split($1,a,"=");print a[2]}'
```