# Similar lines in log, only want to grep 1 of them

Tags: grep

a log generates errors. it generates two very similar lines for 1 error
I want to grep these errors but only one of the lines

for example:

> Line is : Mar 21 15:33:04 VMP05 SMC_User: FATAL ECSDPROD 5210/SUPPORT/ECSD 21/03/17 15:33:04 VMD25 DIR_CHECK 0 FATAL File /data1/gmq6/in/29920991077061 is more than 10 minutes old
>
> Line is : Mar 21 15:33:04 VMP05 SMC_User: FATAL ECSDPROD 5210/SUPPORT/ECSD 21/03/17 15:33:04 VMD18 DIR_CHECK 0 FATAL File /data1/sftp/out/26515991064454 is more than 10 minutes old
>
> Mar 21 15:33:04 VMP05 SMC_User: FATAL ECSDPROD 5210/SUPPORT/ECSD 21/03/17 15:33:04 VMD25 DIR_CHECK 0 FATAL File /data1/gmq6/in/29920991077061 is more than 10 minutes old
>
> Mar 21 15:33:04 VMP05 SMC_User: FATAL ECSDPROD 5210/SUPPORT/ECSD 21/03/17 15:33:04 VMD18 DIR_CHECK 0 FATAL File /data1/sftp/out/26515991064454 is more than 10 minutes old

but I only want to grep the lines without 'Line is'. I am using Hewlett Packard Linux

EDIT:
this grep is needed within a tail -f :

```
    #!/usr/bin/ksh
echo "checking for last 10 fatals"
grep "FATAL ECSDPROD" /data1/log/startstop/MonitorDaemon.log|tail > /tmp/AH/linesDP.txt
grep "FATAL ECSD" /tmp/AH/linesDP.txt | grep -v "Line is"

echo "\n\n----------\n"
echo "checking for new fatals"
tail -f /data1/log/startstop/MonitorDaemon.log | grep "FATAL ECSD" | grep -v "Line is"
echo "about to exit"
exit 0
```

with the above the tail isn't updating, the script gets all the way down to the echo "checking for new fatals" then it won't tail the log

Comment: try `tail...| stdbuf -o 0 awk '/FATAL ECSD/ && !/Line is/'` ... got idea from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617192/buffer-records-in-gnu-awk

Comment: Hi Sundeep, I get the following error ./fatalschkdanp.ksh[8]: stdbuf:  not found
As mentioned we are using Hewlett Packard Linux which isn't exactly the same as normal linux so might not have the stdbuf

Comment: stdbuf not on your machine then... as answered by @Terminator_NL, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858912/piping-tail-output-though-grep-twice should help

Comment: following comes back sorry
grep: illegal option -- -

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://droptips.com/using-grep-to-exclude-lines-containing-certain-characterstext) helps.

`tail -f /data1/log/startstop/MonitorDaemon.log | grep --line-buffered "FATAL ECSD" | grep -v "Line is"`

Elaboration: You can use the pipe symbol ( `|` ) multiple times in one command!

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858912/piping-tail-output-though-grep-twice)

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work.
Technically it does, but what I forgot to explain is I want it to be in a tail. and with this it won't update.
full line 
tail -f /data1/log/startstop/MonitorDaemon.log | grep "FATAL ECSD" | grep -v "Line is"

Comment: Updated answer. The reason it didt work was because of a buffer built into grep, see: [source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858912/piping-tail-output-though-grep-twice)

Comment: the following error comes back
grep: illegal option -- -

Comment: Can you provide a log of the console output and what you put in?

Comment: #!/usr/bin/ksh
echo "Checking For The Last 5 Fatals"
grep "FATAL ECSDPROD" /data1/log/startstop/MonitorDaemon.log|tail > /tmp/AH/linesDP.txt
grep "FATAL ECSD" /tmp/AH/linesDP.txt | grep -v "Line is"

echo "\n\n----------\n"
echo "Checking For New Fatals"
tail -f /data1/log/startstop/MonitorDaemon.log | grep --line-buffered "FATAL ECSD" | grep -v "Line is"
echo "about to exit"
exit 0

Comment: Checking For The Last 5 Fatals
5FATALS LIKE BELOW , 2MANY CHARACTERS 4COMMENT 
Mar 22 09:13:05 VMP05 SMC_User: FATAL ECSDPROD 5210/SUPPORT/ECSD 22/03/17 09:13:04 VMD17 DIR_CHECK 0 FATAL File /data1/gswd/out/26523991712579 is more than 10 minutes old
----------
Checking For New Fatals
grep: illegal option -- -
usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvwx] -e pattern_list...
        [-f pattern_file...] [file...]
usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvwx] [-e pattern_list...]
        -f pattern_file... [file...]
usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvwx] pattern [file...]
about to exit

Answer (score 0):

I think I might of solved this by using a combination of awk and grep.
I am testing it at the moment but so far it works.

```
    #!/usr/bin/ksh
echo "Checking For The Last 5 Fatals"
grep "FATAL ECSDPROD" /data1/log/startstop/MonitorDaemon.log|tail > /tmp/AH/linesDP.txt
grep "FATAL ECSD" /tmp/AH/linesDP.txt | grep -v "Line is"

echo "\n\n----------\n"
echo "Checking For New Fatals"
tail -f /data1/log/startstop/MonitorDaemon.log | awk '/FATAL ECS/' | grep -v "Line is"
echo "about to exit"
exit 0
```