# No output from ''tail -f | gawk | tee''; either ''tail -f | gawk'' or ''gawk | tee'' works fine

Tags: bash, shell, awk, command-line-interface, tee

`tee` works fine if placed before the gawk command, but not at all if placed after. Is it not possible to use after gawk?

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT_DATE=`date -u +%Y-%m-%d`

tail -fn0 /var/log/pi-star/MMDVM-"$CURRENT_DATE".log | gawk ' match($0, 
/received.*voice header from ([[:alnum:]]+) to ([[:alnum:]]+ [0-9]+)/, 
a) {
in_record = 1
call_sign = a[1]
channel = a[2]
}
in_record && match($0, /DMR ID: ([0-9]+)/, a) {
dmr_id = a[1]
}
in_record && match($0, /([0-9.]+) seconds, ([0-9]+)% packet loss, BER: 
([0-9.]+)%/, a) {
in_record = 0
print call_sign, channel, dmr_id, a[1], a[2], a[3]
} ' OFS=, | tee -a log.txt
```

EDITED - Using the above bash script  when placing the tee command after TAIL but before GAWK I get a perfect replication of the original log that is being tailed, but with it comes all the unneeded information that GAWK is to filter. When I place the tee command at the end of the file (as it is above) nothing goes into the log.txt file and nothing is displayed on the screen as the original log changes.

Here is a portion of the original logfile that is in the tail command.

```
M: 2019-06-10 00:00:03.667 DMR Slot 2, received network voice header 
from W3DON to TG 310
M: 2019-06-10 00:00:03.911 DMR Slot 2, received network end of voice 
transmission, 0.5 seconds, 0% packet loss, BER: 0.0%
M: 2019-06-10 00:00:11.611 DMR Slot 2, received network voice header 
from KD2QDD to TG 310
M: 2019-06-10 00:00:11.634 DMR Slot 2, received network end of voice 
transmission, 0.5 seconds, 12% packet loss, BER: 0.0%
M: 2019-06-10 00:00:12.703 DMR Slot 2, received network voice header 
from IZ0LDE to TG 310
M: 2019-06-10 00:00:13.932 DMR Slot 2, received network end of voice 
transmission, 1.2 seconds, 0% packet loss, BER: 0.0%
M: 2019-06-10 00:00:20.426 DMR Slot 2, received network voice header 
from N1GMB to TG 310
M: 2019-06-10 00:00:26.293 DMR Slot 2, received network end of voice 
transmission, 6.7 seconds, 9% packet loss, BER: 0.0%
M: 2019-06-10 00:00:34.722 DMR Slot 2, received network voice header 
from N1GMB to TG 310
M: 2019-06-10 00:00:35.197 DMR Talker Alias (Data Format 1, Received 
6/10 char): 'TAC 31'
M: 2019-06-10 00:00:35.197 DMR Slot 2, Embedded Talker Alias Header
M: 2019-06-10 00:00:35.197 0000:  04 00 54 54 41 43 20 33 31                         
*..TTAC 31*
M: 2019-06-10 00:00:35.892 DMR Talker Alias (Data Format 1, Received 
10/10 char): 'TAC 310 NC'
M: 2019-06-10 00:00:35.892 DMR Slot 2, Embedded Talker Alias Block 1
M: 2019-06-10 00:00:35.892 0000:  05 00 30 20 4E 43 00 00 00                         
*..0 NC...*
M: 2019-06-10 00:00:52.569 DMR Slot 2, received network end of voice 
transmission, 18.2 seconds, 2% packet loss, BER: 0.0%
M: 2019-06-10 00:00:53.700 DMR Slot 2, received network voice header 
from K6FCC to TG 310
M: 2019-06-10 00:00:53.851 DMR Slot 2, received network end of voice 
transmission, 0.5 seconds, 0% packet loss, BER: 0.0%
M: 2019-06-10 00:00:54.605 DMR Slot 2, received network voice header 
from KC8QCH to TG 310
M: 2019-06-10 00:00:56.168 DMR Slot 2, network watchdog has expired, 
1.8 seconds, 80% packet loss, BER: 0.0%
M: 2019-06-10 00:01:01.253 DMR Slot 2, received network voice header 
from N1GMB to TG 310
M: 2019-06-10 00:01:01.735 DMR Talker Alias (Data Format 1, Received 
6/10 char): 'TAC 31'
M: 2019-06-10 00:01:01.735 DMR Slot 2, Embedded Talker Alias Header
M: 2019-06-10 00:01:01.735 0000:  04 00 54 54 41 43 20 33 31                         
*..TTAC 31*
M: 2019-06-10 00:01:02.426 DMR Talker Alias (Data Format 1, Received 
10/10 char): 'TAC 310 NC'
M: 2019-06-10 00:01:02.426 DMR Slot 2, Embedded Talker Alias Block 1
M: 2019-06-10 00:01:02.426 0000:  05 00 30 20 4E 43 00 00 00                         
*..0 NC...*
M: 2019-06-10 00:01:06.507 DMR Slot 2, received network end of voice 
transmission, 5.5 seconds, 1% packet loss, BER: 0.0%
```

Using the GAWK command cleanses it the above down content such as this:

> K6ASF,TG 310,3158238,0.5,0,0.0

Does that help clarify?

Comment: Why do you think tee doesn't work when placed after gawk? Don't just describe your problem, *show* your problem -- a question should contain enough information to let someone else see the problem for themselves (which isn't the case here; nobody else is likely to have a `/var/log/pi-star`).

Comment: Anyhow, it's easy to generate a standalone test case for which `gawk | tee` works fine; try `printf '%s\n' 1 2 3 | gawk 1 | tee test.log`. Your job is to come up with a comparably standalone test case for which it doesn't. :)

Comment: @MikeWodarczyk, nope, `OFS=,` and `OFS=','` are syntactically identical in a position where the quotes will be consumed by the shell (though it *is* an unusual position to be putting that; I'd generally expect it to be in a BEGIN block inside the awk code itself).

Comment: I think the tail -f is key. It keeps stdout open. Tee and gawk  appear to buffer stdin differently when stdin is not closed.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/742238/piping-tail-f-into-awk. For solutions on piping into gawk/awk. It has to do with the shell buffering the pipe data. Tee acts like a terminal and doesn’t suffer from buffering challenges.

Comment: Tail must be a terminated command you are saying Mike?

Comment: Nope. It'll all get flushed eventually, you're just waiting for the buffer to fill. See [BashFAQ #9](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009).

Comment: @MikeWodarczyk, it's not the shell doing the buffering, it's the standard C library functions used by the various programs in the pipeline. The shell isn't involved in the communications at all -- it just wires up program-A's stdout to program-B's stdin before starting the programs in a pipeline; after which those programs communicate directly.

Comment: @JaeNulton, ...so, what you're seeing here is awk buffering output when it's going to a pipeline (since that's lower-overhead), but writing it immediately when it's going to a TTY (since a user at a TTY will typically want to see results immediately). That's normal default behavior, and calling `fflush()` from your awk program will avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `fflush()` from your awk program to force output to be immediately written, even when not to a TTY.

That is to say -- *after* your `print` command, add an extra command `fflush()`.

<sub>Marked Community Wiki to avoid gaining reputation/points from answering [a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617192/buffer-records-in-gnu-awk).</sub>

Comment: Charles, I am sure you know already, but it worked perfectly! Thank you also for the tips on how to better post my questions here, I am very new and definitely still learning. Sorry for the delay in getting back and marking as answered, had an international phone call come in. Mike thank you for you efforts and best guesses as well the excellent link you sent.

Comment: Also thank you for the edits Charles, much appreciated.